# Updating notifications from IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-notifications

I'm relatively new to Android and I'm looking for some advice/best practises on using notifications from an IntentService.

I have an IntentService which uploads files, and shows progress in a notification (A). After each upload, another notification (B) is updated with the filename and such.

To be able to update notification B with all the filenames, I keep a static ArrayList with all the names. As long as notification B is shown, I want to keep updating it, but if it is dismissed I want to start over.
There is a setDeleteIntent which I can set on notification B, but then I have to call an activity, just to make that class clear the static list. Are there other ways to do this? 
I'm not really a fan of the static list approach either - any ideas here?

Comment: Can you give some more information ? Notifications can be set via an intent service as well. Pass the data you want regarding the specific notification by setting a Bundle extra & filling what you want.

Comment: I am using an IntentService to upload and set notifications. I just want to remember the uploaded file names between each time onHandleIntent is called. Does that make sense? Currently using a static ArrayList, but that just doesn't seem like the best idea to me.